# Apple ID auto log in

Tags: iphone

I'm on my iphone 5s if my sister get iphone and we have same apple id.
Example i download instagram it auto log me in. Will it do on her device also?
Please help

Comment: Your question is not clear.  Do you mean if you and your sister are using the same iPhone 5S with the same Apple ID?

Comment: Apple ids are not meant to be shared. Use your own.

Answer (score 1):

Same AppleID, eh?  Would you get each others' Facetime calls?  Would you be responsible for paying for her "in-game" purchases?  I guess you can set up "Parental Controls" (with you as the parent) to limit what she can do.  But is that really what you want?  Why not let her get her own AppleID?  There is a "family plan" for sharing downloads.